# C# Adding a tabpage to a listView

Tags: c#, listview, tabpage

I have a window form application, and in that I have a ListView called lstView.
How do I add a tabpage to that through code.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is your code

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
   TabControl tbl = new TabControl();
   tbl.TabPages.Add("page1");            
   lstView.Controls.Add(tbl);
}
```

Comment: tank you, thats what I needed :)